# SQL Mutli criteria update query in single column

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi All I'm really new to SQL coding, I've used VBA alot previously but i'm a bit stumped with SQL.

I have a database that currently holds about 20,000 records. to keep it simple i have a column called `Request` within this each record shows `Confirmation of cover` or `Decline Letter` etc

I need to update every single record to new wording like this:

`Confirmation of cover` update to `New Confirmation of Cover` then 
`Decline Letter` update to `New Decline Letter` etc etc

If i use the wizard it allows me to update 1 request reason type at a time but i want to be able to just complete this for each request reason.

I hope this makes sense.

Kind Regards
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a bad idea to have a column with only a few possible, known strings in it. Consider making a new table for that column, associating an ID with the two possibilities.

To update multiple rows, do this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

[This is from the W3School documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

If you want to avoid having to go through a whole database, instead create a new table for requests and have each row be a possible request-string, and refer to the row using a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Hi Christian thank you for your fast response, to update a bit further the reason its like this is because its for admin requests. so my column headings are for example: ID, Customer Name, Request. The rquest heading is where the user has selected their reason for the request. and i have just been asked to update the request reasons. thus giving me this headache. i hope that cleared it up :-)

Comment: If you know the possible request reasons, you might as well have a separate table with each possible request reason and refer to it with a foreign key ID. Or is what you are asking to concatenate "New" to the front of each reason?

Comment: I have the old set of request reasons and now have the new set of request reasons, about 9 of the reasons have changed mostly just by a few words. but i have to update whats already been requested for Data MI purposes. as i said i'm completely new to SQL, oh and i forgot to mention this is all within MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

If it is Microsoft SQL Server, you can try following (but will be same for other variants of SQL as well):

```
UPDATE <Your Table Name>
SET Request = CASE WHEN 'Confirmation of cover' THEN 'New Confirmation of Cover' 
         WHEN 'Decline Letter' THEN 'New Decline Letter'
         ELSE Request END
```

You can add more conditions using `When` clause the `Else` part leaves the original value if it does not matches any of your criteria.

Comment: Hi, I'm Using Microsoft Access and seem to get a Syntax error when using the above....

Answer (score 0):

In Access, I think you can do:

```
UPDATE <Your Table Name>
    SET Request = "New " & Request
    WHERE Request in ("Confirmation of cover", "Decline Letter");
```